# How to connect to Exchange Server on non domain PC

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-outlook-2019

Is it possible to connect to Exchange server without being member of domain network?

Answer (score 0):

Because outlook just support auto discover method for connection we must add fake DNS record to our system.

ping your domain mail address like mail.yourdomain.com and copy ip of it(for sample 172.20.26.32).

```
ping mail.yourdomain.com
```

then add below records to your hosts file(C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) and restart system.

```
172.20.26.32 mail.yourdomain.com
172.20.26.32 autodiscover.yourdomain.com
```

Thanks to [Ben Oostdam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhEcI7y_X_0)